# how to curve cylinder like image below

Tags: modeling

[image]

I want to curve the cylinder so it would be like a rotating ramp

Comment: so what's happening on the other side?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: how does the curve continue on the side we don't see? is it a half cylinder?

Comment: Make another curve, possible from a curve object converted to mesh, and shrinkwrap/project the top verts in Z axis onto that curve object.  Or, use a knife project operation to cut one mesh with the other, then clean up afterwards.

Comment: i am a noob at this, possible to dumbify that?

Comment: If you're a noob, then learn the components of what I mentioned.  Learn how to make a curve object.  Learn how to use a knife project.  Learn how use a shrinkwrap modifier.  All of the components of the answer have been answered elsewhere, and when you understand the components of the answer, you'll understand the answer.

Comment: Hello :). Something like this? [How to model Helix shaped ramp?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/105960/78972)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like that?

[image]